# Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute. This message is shown to subscriber and general user

Tags: maintenance

I am receiving message `Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute`."
When i normally browse the url.

Wordpress version (4.7.4)

- If i log as administrator and browse the site , everything is running properly
- If i log as any user below administrator (editor,subscriber,editor). I am getting maintenance page
- Access without login same maintenance page is shown

Please provide any guidance on the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess, something wrong happened during WordPress or an active plugin or the active theme update. Maybe connection loss or interruption.

Have a look at WordPress root directory. If the (hidden) file named `.maintenance` exists, then safely remove it. It's the temporary file used by WordPress for few minutes until the update process is finished. Likely, it was not deleted for some reason.

Comment: i checked their is no .maintenance  file. Secondly only administrator is able to view the site. Other role user are not able to browse

Comment: Did you use an FTP client with `show hidden files` option enabled to check the existence of that file?

Comment: Yes, it is enable